# enunciate does not work when source directory add

Tags: java, enunciate, maven-compiler-plugin

I generated doc with enunciate plugin and it worked, I add a source directory for adding extra file to classpath for compile(maven-compiler-plugin).enunciate does not work with this.how i solve this problem?
i get this error :
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.enunciate:maven-enunciate-plugin:1.27:assemble : Problem assembling the enunciate app. The invocation of APT has failed. See http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/ENUNCIATE-771 for a case where this has been seen. There is no explanation for this error. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: Hi Paria, I would like to add extra source file to enunciate so that it can generate docs for these sources as well. How did you do that ?

Answer (score 3):

The Annotation Processing Tool (APT) that Enunciate uses is notorious for unhelpful error messages. An APT failure usually implies some kind of compile failure. Try compiling your project by skipping the Enunciate step to expose the compile failure:

`mvn -Denunciate.skip=true`

Or, you can try having Enunciate do a compile check before it invokes APT:

`mvn -Denunciate.javac.check=true`

This might expose the real problem.

Comment: Works but I have to use -DenunciateSkip=true